# How to access a domain that resolves to 127.0.0.1 from inside a docker container?

Tags: docker

I have a dev domain http://local.dev.com in my hosts file that points to 127.0.0.1.
Currently the docker container I'm running it's just trying to resolve 127.0.0.1 but fails because it can't access the host machine's server.

The fail comes from a nodejs script

```
We received this error at the network level:

  > Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:2019
```

Is there a way to allow access from the container to the host machine domain ?

Comment: You need to make that address resolve to something other than the `localhost` address. E.g., place an entry in your container's `/etc/hosts` file (using the `--add-host`) option that maps `local.dev.com` to the ip address of one of your host's interfaces.

Comment: Thanks I was able to make this work with the following 
`--add-host=local.dev.com:host-gateway`